# How to disable a clusted scheduled task using powershell

Tags: scheduled-tasks, powershell-2.0

Need to disable a clusterschduled task in windows 2012, using following command
however it is not disabling clusterscheduled tasks.

get-ClusteredScheduledTask -disable

Disable-ScheduledTask -TaskName

Comment: Related link: http://serverfault.com/questions/628958/how-to-enable-or-disable-a-clusteredscheduledtask-in-powershell-4-0. Is it possible that the capitalization is different between what's returned from get-ClusteredScheduledTask and what you're using in Disable-ScheduledTask? Could you post the actual task names that are not being properly disabled. or the actual powershell you're using including variables and/or string literals?

Comment: Hi,I am using following command to disable scheduled task  get-ClusteredScheduledTask | Disable-ScheduledTask -TaskName "schTest 123"        Error message is : ----- Disable-ScheduledTask : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties 
do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At C:\Users\smannam\Desktop\schePOC.ps1:134 char:30
+ get-ClusteredScheduledTask | Disable-ScheduledTask -TaskName

Answer (score 0):

The pipe | is causing the entire set of objects returned from get-ClusteredScheduledTasks to be passed to the Disable-ScheduledTask. The use of the -TaskName is causing an error in the Disable-ScheduledTask command, because the pipe tells it "apply this command to these objects," but you then immediately try to apply the command to a single task named "schTest 123". [This article](http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/powershell-piping-filtering-objects,2-771.html) provides some deeper explanation on command piping.

A couple different ways to solve this, depending on what you're trying to do:

1) If your goal is to disable ALL tasks that are currently scheduled:

```
$tasks = get-ScheduledTasks | where { $_.State -eq "Ready" } # exclude any tasks that are already disabled so we don't accidentally re-enable them later
$tasks | Disable-ScheduledTask
# do your work
$tasks | Enable-ScheduledTask
```

OR

```
$tasks = get-ScheduledTasks | where { $_.State -eq "Ready" }
$tasks | foreach { Disable-ScheduledTask -TaskName $_.TaskName }
# do your work
$tasks | foreach { Enable-ScheduledTask -TaskName $_.TaskName }
```

These are functionally identical, but the first one is certainly semantically cleaner.

2) If your goal is to disable only a single task by name

```
Disable-ScheduledTask -TaskName $myTaskName
# do your work
Enable-ScheduledTask -TaskName $myTaskName
```

3) If you want to be certain a single task exists prior to disabling/enabling

```
$task = get-ClusteredScheduledTasks | where { $_.TaskName -eq $myTaskName }
if ( $task -eq $Null ) { throw ( "Could not find scheduled task " + $myTaskName ) }
Disable-ScheduledTask -TaskName $task.TaskName
# do work
Enable-ScheduledTask -TaskName $task.TaskName
```